# how to plot the median of many curve in the some fig

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to plot the median of many curve in the some fig with using numpy.median but it doesn't work.I don't know where is the problem.This is the scrip please help

```
import numpy

import pylab

filename= "D:\exercices python\generale.csv"

Data=numpy.genfromtxt(filename,delimiter=";",skip_header=5)

fig=pylab.figure()

ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.invert_yaxis()

headerList = [(ax.plot(Data[:,i],Data[:,0],'-',color='k', alpha=0.2)) for i in range (1,60)]

ax.plot(numpy.median(Data[:,1],axis=1), Data [:,0],'-' ,color='r', linewidth=5)

pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The median only returns one number, if you want to plot a straight line where the median runs you might do it by specifying one point at the beginning of the curve and one at the end, both with the value of the median:

```
m = np.median (Data[:,1])
ax.plot ([m, m], Data[[0, -1], 0])
```

here assuming that the argument array `Data[:,0]` is linearly increasing, we pick the first and last element of it.

Comment: `ax.hlines()` is a shorter way to draw horizontal lines in matplotlib.